# SQL issue - CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone spot an issue with this case when statement? SQL Server doesn't seem to like it and I can't spot the issue!

```
SELECT CASE @Next_Insp_Date
    WHEN @Purpose_ID = 1 THEN DATEADD(m, 6, GETDATE()) AS @Next_Insp_Date
    WHEN @Purpose_ID = 2 THEN DATEADD(m, 12, GETDATE()) AS @Next_Insp_Date
    ELSE @Next_Insp_Date
END AS @Next_Insp_Date
```

Comment: There are many issues wrong with this case statement... I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: have you looked up the documentation of case ? And have you looked at an example ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A case statement can have only **one** alias. Try like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @Purpose_ID = 1 THEN DATEADD(m, 6, GETDATE()) 
    WHEN @Purpose_ID = 2 THEN DATEADD(m, 12, GETDATE())
    ELSE --some other value here
END AS Some_alias_name -- here it is the alias
```

I don't know what `@Next_Insp_Date` holds but sure it is in the wrong place. In the else statement you should have anotther value

If you want to retrieve the value from `@Next_Insp_Date` then it should go in the else statement.

Comment: @GuidoG yeah, that's why I added that last sentence. I will remove that var from the query.

Comment: That's what I was looking for just constructed it wrong on this occasion. Thanks Jorge!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CASE @Purpose_ID
    WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(m, 6, GETDATE())
    WHEN 2 THEN DATEADD(m, 12, GETDATE())
    ELSE @Next_Insp_Date
END
```

Not sure what the intention of `AS @Next_Insp_Date` is, the alias belongs after the `END` if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

Your column alias is `@Next_Insp_Date`, which it can't be unless you quote it. You probably intended to name it Next_Insp_Date.

Also, you are mixing the two CASE styles of `CASE @val when 1 then` and `CASE WHEN @val = 1 then`

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN @Purpose_ID = 1 THEN DATEADD(m, 6, GETDATE())
    WHEN @Purpose_ID = 2 THEN DATEADD(m, 12, GETDATE())
    ELSE @Next_Insp_Date
END AS [Next_Insp_Date]
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @Next_Insp_Date datetime = getdate();
declare @Purpose_ID int = 3;

SELECT @Next_Insp_Date = CASE WHEN @Purpose_ID = 1 THEN DATEADD(m, 6, GETDATE()) 
WHEN @Purpose_ID = 2 THEN DATEADD(m, 12, GETDATE()) 
ELSE @Next_Insp_Date END 
print @Next_Insp_Date;

Comment: Hi there, when adding a code as an answer (or even a question), please format it. You just need to add four spaces before every code line. I did it this time. You are on, in the next!